why is my Custom CSS in Blazor is Not working?
i created a Login.Razor.css file in the same folder as my Login Comp , but the css is not applying att all even after calling in in the header link in HTML of Login .

Any idea on how to solve this .

Read the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0 and specifically this section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#css-isolation-bundling

To make blazor isolation work, you need to add the following <link> element:
<link href="{ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

For more information, you can read the article and this question

There is no Issue here other than a missing Capital L in the import of the login css .
